# How to remove "Send to other device with SHAREit" from context menu

Tags: context-menu

How to remove "Send to other device with SHAREit" from context menu?
I look at the add remove software on my `Windows 8.1` or `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)`, there are no thing called "ShareIt". I'm using Lenovo ThinkPad.

[image: Send to other device with SHAREit]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because self-created and self-solved mistake.

Comment: The answer is good, and the problem was real. I do not believe this should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it on the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\ShareIt\uninst001.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I removed the whole ShareIt folder from "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\UpdateEncryptionSettingsWork" and it did work.